# How to add sstablesplit to an existing Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I am a beginner in Cassandra and currently have a small cluster with replication factor 3 and most of the parameters being set to default.

What I noticed the other day is that the SSTables have become absolutely massive (>1TB) and the logs are now starting to complain that they cannot perform a compaction anymore. I've looked into it and decided to switch to the LevelCompactionStrategy, as well as performing an `sstablesplit` on my existing SSTables.

However, at that point I noticed that sstablesplit did not come with my installation of Cassandra. Is there a way of installing just that tool? All the guides I've seen talk about installing the entire Datastax tech stack, which would probably invalidate my existing cluster or require a great deal of reinstalling which at the moment I cannot do. The Cassandra installation was not set up by me.

At the same time, LCS is complaining that it cannot perform re-compaction because it's trying to recompact all SSTables at once, which, since they now take slightly more than 50% of hard drive space, it can't find enough space to do.

If sstablesplit is impossible (or inadvisable), is there any other way to resolve my issue of having several SSTables which are too massive to be re-compacted into more manageable chunks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sstablesplit is part of the cassandra codebase, you can use it even without it being packaged. The cassandra-all jar and  lib jars to classpath have everything to run it. This is all the sstablesplit script does: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/tools/bin/sstablesplit.

Is this in AWS or some cloud platform where you can get larger hosts temporarily? Easiest is to replace the hosts with new hosts with 2x the disk space or something, migrate to LCS then switch back for costs.

Comment: I guess the other question to mention here is, Will compacting the massive sstables actually shrink the resultant size? If you don't have rows split across multiple sstables, expired ttls, or tombstones, compacting it, no matter how you do it, won't save you any space. In that case, the solution would be to add more nodes to spread the data out v.s. trying to compact data that, in the end, won't provide benefit. I'm guessing your thought is that compaction will actually shrink the data size due to rows existing across multiple sstables, expired ttls, or deletes (tombstone cleanup).

Comment: I am aware that the resulting total size will not change, it's the overhead that will - LCS requires barely any overhead (size of SSTable, I believe), while STCS needs the sum of current SSTables of extra space to compact them to the new one.

Comment: I would still recommend keeping it below ~80% for LCS (more to make sure you have time to expand if your hitting limits) but definitely more cost effective than STCS, especially on cloud infrastructure where you care less about the write amplifications effect on SSD life.